# Java synchronized String IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java, multithreading, blackberry

I'm trying to have a Thread2 wait for a String and Thread1 to notify on String update, I do synchronize The String object as code below shows, But I still get `IllegalMonitorStateException` Here's my code

```
public class Class1{

String string   = "";

public Class1(){


    Thread t1   = new Thread(){

        public void run(){

            synchronized(string){

                string = "Something"; string.notifyAll();   //This is the line that throws an IllegalMonitorStateException
            }

        }

    };


    Thread t2   = new Thread(){

        public void run(){

            synchronized(string){

                try{

                    string.wait();

                }catch(Exception e){

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }

        }

    };

    t2.start();
    t1.start();
}

}
```

There's nothing in StackTrace except highlighting `string.notifyAll()`

Comment: I am not getting any `IllegalMonitorStateException`.

Comment: When you are talking about a "String update", one has to assume that the *instance* that is represented by the variable `string` changes (and af course, that the code you provided is *not* the code that causes the error)

Comment: @Braj I figured it might be a BlackBerry problem @Marco13 yes I'm changing the value of `string`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your code contains a data race because it accesses the mutable `string` variable outside of a `synchronized` block. Specifically, this happens on the line `synchronized(string)`. While dereferencing `string` to reach the object whose monitor will be locked, the thread does not already hold a lock on that object. Therefore you have no guarantee which object it will acquire a lock on.
2. The fact that you *mutate* the `string` variable means that it now points to some other object. When the next thread acquires a lock on that new object, it will not benefit from any *happens-before* relationship because it is the first thread to ever acquire a lock on it. Mutual exclusion will not be guaranteed, either, because there may be arbitrarily many threads, each locking a different `String` instance without contention.
3. Combining the two phenomena described above we can also see that there is no guarantee that the object reached on the line `synchronized(string)` will be the same one as the one reached from *within* the synchronized block. Once it happens that this is indeed a different object, your `IllegalMonitorStateException` ensues.

In summary, the situation is very similar to the `synchronized` block not existing at all.

All of the above problems can be avoided if you keep to the best practice of using dedicated `final` variables to refer to objects used for locking. In a nutshell, and fixing the compilation errors in your example, this is what you would have to write:

```
static String string = "";
static final Object lock = new Object();

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Thread t1 = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
      synchronized (lock) {
        ... update the string variable ...
        lock.notifyAll();
      }
    }
  };
  Thread t2 = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
      synchronized (lock) {
        try {
          lock.wait();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  };
  t2.start();
  t1.start();
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter Please leave a comment, what is wrong with this answer? Can it be improved?

Comment: @meLove most of the point of `final` is to stop you updating it. This answer is slightly misleading. Adding `final` does not solve your problem - your problem is partially solved by not updating the variable, which `final` enforces.

Comment: @immibis I believe that the code example makes this answer as clear as they get. Or can you suggest how I can improve it even further?

Comment: @WilliamF.Jameson "your issue is very probably due to synchronizing on a non-`final` variable" - it doesn't matter whether the variable is `final`; what matters is whether the value is changed.

Comment: @immibis OK, I removed that, but I would call this quite moot because 1) the exception definitely disappears if you lock on a `final` variable; 2) it is a *best practice* to always lock on dedicated `final` variables, therefore the issue has arisen due to failing to follow that best practice; 3) there is always a risk that a non-final variable *may* be changed somewhere, or that such code may be introduced later on; so even if you currently do not have symptoms, it is *still* an issue if you lock on a non-final variable; 4) you may have safe publication issues with non-final variables.

Comment: @WilliamF.Jameson I think I am with immibis on this one.  Your comment "2) it is a best practice to always lock on dedicated final variables" seems to be to be missing the point. Synchronization requires agreement on the objects to be used - there is no requirement for these to be final.  And the problem in this case was that the OP was assuming one reference meant one object, so the important point in answering this question was to explain the OPs misunderstanding rather than prescribe the use of final.

Comment: @PeterStrange There is a requirement that the object to be locked is not reached in a data race, and that is what OP is doing, and would not be doing if the lock variable was `final`. Anyway, I have revised the answer once more, you can review it if you like.